# Can not upload Unity WebGL in ASP.Net MVC with an error of “The error was: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<”

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to insert a game into an asp.Net mvc but when I compile the following error occurs:

An error occurred while running the Unity content on this page. See your browser JavaScript console for more info. The error was:
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
An error occurred running the Unity content on this page. See your browser JavaScript console for more info. The error was:
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

ASP NET MVC:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjAal.png
[image]
Console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo5JH.png

[image]

```html
<script src="~/WebGL/Memoria/Facil/TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>
<script src="~/WebGL/Memoria/Facil/Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
<script>
    var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "../WebGL/Memoria/Facil/Build/memoria.json", { onProgress: UnityProgress });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="webgl-content">
    <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="fullscreen" onclick="gameInstance.SetFullscreen(1)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not know what's happening, can anyone help me?

Comment: Usually means that you expected a JSON as response but instead got an error HTML response like e.g. 404-Not found. Results in the first character being an HTML tag `<` instead of a JSON

Comment: can you help me? i'm trying to load this file in the .cshtml, but i dont now what i'm doing Wrong.  https://i.imgur.com/liR1Hjj.png

Comment: Is it possible that for some reason `~/WebGL/Memoria/Facil/Build/UnityLoader.js` is not found and therefore the type `UnityLoader` does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Url "../WebGL/Memoria/Facil/Build/memoria.json"
The correct is: "~/WebGL/Memoria/Facil/Build/memoria.json"

but now another error occurs:
unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

ps: this error only happens when this in the asp.net mvc project, in html normal it works normally

Answer (score 0):

Are these script tags within an HTML file or any external .js file?

If these are in external .js file, then the syntax error is because of writing  tags in the .js file.

You don't need the  tags in an external .js file. These tags are used to embed a script inside HTML.

Comment: it's a HTML file